# Python precision math calculation in interpreter and script without typing decimal module all the time

Tags: python, math, decimal, precision

I noticed that the math operation in python is not as precise as before, especially the one involves float numbers. I know it is due to the nature of binary number representation, and we can get through this problem by doing:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
a = Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2')
```

I can even do something further like:

```py
def func(a, b, operator):
    a_ = Decimal('{}'.format(a))
    b_ = Decimal('{}'.format(b))
    return eval('float(a_ {} b_)'.format(operator))

func(0.1, 0.2, '+') # will return 0.3
```

However, I do not want to go this far. In fact, I was using python as calculator or a Matlab alternative all the time. Having to write a lot more stuff for a quick calculation is not convenient. The context setting for the decimal module also requires to write "Decimal" in front of the number.

[This 5-year-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229505/how-to-set-the-decimal-precision-globally-in-python-without-always-typing-decima) focused on the script instead of a working inside an interpreter. I also tried the [code example](https://github.com/abarnert/floatliteralhack) but it is not working as expected.

Is there a quick and dirty way to make python execute `0.1 + 0.2` have the same result of `float(Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2'))`?
It should be also applied to the other math operations like `**` and equality comparison like `==`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not as precise _as before_"? Before when? The fundamentals of Python's floating-point arithmetic haven't changed in decades.

Comment: Matlab and Python produce the same value for `0.1+0.2`. Both produce exactly `0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`. Matlab hides the additional decimals but `fprintf('%.52f',0.1+0.2)` will show the full value. This is a limitation of fixed floating point precision used by basically all modern languages. What you're seeing is a difference of printed precision, not a difference of actual values in memory.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I believe that it might be as what jodag said: the previous version might hide the real result by elimnating additional decimals. I forgot the version, but it returned the real decimals after a specific version. Perhaps something wrong in my memory.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I believe that this question is not a duplicate because the answer provided works for a script only in my opinion. The float was not rewind as a string literal to the Decimal constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a new object type called `D` (for decimal).

```
from decimal import Decimal

class D:
  def __init__(self, d: float | int):
    self.d = Decimal(str(d))

  def __add__(self, other_d: D):
    return self.d + other_d.d
```

By overwriting the `__add__` method on `D`, you can recreate the addition behaviour you want. In the same way, you can overwrite the magic method corresponding to each of the arithmetic operators. (e.g. overwrite `__eq__` for `==`, etc)

Once this is in place you can do something like:

```
a = D(0.1)
b = D(0.3)
c = a + b

print(c)
-> 0.4 (Decimal type)
```

Comment: Note, the typing on the arguments (e.g. `d: float | int`, and `other_d: D`) are python version dependent. If they give errors, just remove them.

Comment: This doesn't seem any better than just using `D=Decimal`

Comment: Using the internal method within a new class is a good way to do. However, is there a way to change how python interpret float literals to Decimal class string input? As the result, after doing a series of things, I can just type `0.1+0.2`, which will return 0.3?

Comment: @ONLYA it's an interesting question, and a related one is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880276/12705481. The gist comes down to abstract syntax trees; these are the data structures that store the written python code as a sequence of instructions for the compiler. You can interact with them via the `ast` standard library module. There may be a way to do what you want to do, though if there is it's very fundamental and tricky stuff (and certainly beyond my comprehension!). My solution, at the very least, provides a shorthand.

Comment: @jodag the advantage is the string conversion. If you do `Decimal(0.1)` you get the rounding errors. So you have to do `Decimal("0.1")` to avoid the rounding errors. This solution gets us closer to using "raw" floats.

Comment: @Alan Thanks. I did a little research on this but it appears to transform the AST for a script file instead of the interpreter. I can run this in the interpreter like `exec(compile(transformed, '<unknown>', "exec"))` but I have to call it every time with the transformed version in the interpreter. Perhaps this is only viable for the script file but not the direct interpreter input.